# Find sum from combination of array elements

Tags: java, algorithm, sum

I have an array such as below:

```
int[] numberArray = {9,2,1,5,6};
```

I want to devise a method that will take an integer as an argument and return true/false depending if the argument can be achieved by summing any of the numbers in that array.

```
public boolean sumCheck (int sum) {
    // ...
}
```

For example, if `sum` were `5`, `sumCheck` would return true since `numberArray[3] == 5`. If `sum` were `12`, `sumCheck` would return true since `numberArray[0]+numberArray[1]+numberArray[2] == 12`. It would not return true, however, if `sum` were `4`, as no combination of `numberArray` elements can sum to this number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem, which is NP-complete. However, you can find a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm (a variant of knapsack, using DP) on the Wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/..it explains your problem in a nice way. First brute force then dp solution is there.